# Access constant without self::?

Tags: php, constants

I'd like to use some constants with a function, but it is laborious and ugly to refer to them with `self::` every time. Is there a way to just access them by name without specifying scope?

```
class My_Class {    
    const CLASS_CONSTANT = 'test value';
    private function my_function(){
         // Is there a way to access this without self::
         $a = self::CLASS_CONSTANT;
    }
}
```

Comment: First of all what ugly means to you? And why it's a reason not to use `self::`. Also you can do: `My_Class::CLASS_CONSTANT`

Comment: I kept the example simple, but suppose you have ten constants that you use five times each in a function. That's a lot of `self::` or `My_Class::` to repeat. Redundant code is ugly to me.

Comment: What if you have same constant in two different classes? Isn't `self::` and `ThatClass::` suggestive and useful?

Comment: No, it's not for my use case. That's why I'm asking the question.

Answer (score 1):

One possible (but clunky) way to achieve this, is using the [define()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.define.php) function. The only problem with this approach is that it defines the variable in a global scope.

Here is how to use it:

```php
define ('text', 'Foo Bar?!');

echo text;
```

Will return: `Foo Bar?!`

So to integrate this into a class you can do the following:

```php
class My_Class{
  function __construct(){
      define ('CLASS_CONSTANT', 'test value');  
    }

  private function display(){
      echo CLASS_CONSTANT;
    }
}

$example = new My_Class();
$example->display();
```

This outputs: `test value`

Do note that [define()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.define.php) is a function, and as such requires to be executed inside of a function block, or outside of the class. It can not be easily declared at the top of a class like normal class constants.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ReflectionClass` to get all the constants of a class

```
    $oClass = new \ReflectionClass(My_Class::class);
    $constants = $oClass->getConstants();
    foreach ($constants as $name => $value) {
        //to work
    }
```

For more visit: http://php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.getconstants.php

Hope it helps!